# I accidentlly wiped my device with Android Device Manager

Tags: hardware, android-device-manager

I accidentally deleted my phone through Android Device Manager as I thought it was stolen. I have found the phone.

Can I still use the phone, or is it no longer usable since it has been wiped from Android Device Manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. What you did only completely wipes the phone(all stored data, contacts, etc will be lost). You should be able to set it up again and get it running for you.